# No such file or directory when adding arguments to Gradle exec task

Tags: gradle

I am making task which runs bash script

```
task wsUpload(type: Exec) {
  commandLine '../scripts/ws_upload.sh ' + rootProject.ext.VERSION_CODE
}
```

however it returns

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "../scripts/ws_upload.sh 30" .... No such file or directory
```

if i ran same command without arguments

```
 task wsUpload(type: Exec) {
      commandLine '../scripts/ws_upload.sh'
    }
```

then command is executed. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: need to add args separately as a na array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add args like this

```
task wsUpload(type: Exec) {
      commandLine '../scripts/ws_upload.sh'
      args = ["args"]
    }
```